# C# TextBox Input from Form1 to Form Name Output in Form2?

Tags: c#, input, output

I need help with a code that brings the Input of a textbox into another form as FormName(FormText).Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned there are many examples on this site, here is one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassingDataBetweenForms
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private readonly string _input;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Form2(string input)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _input = input;
            Shown += OnShown;
            
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = _input;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```